# How do I sort an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In an array T we have values `[b,a,d,c]`. How to reorder this array in a single loop in the aim to get `[a,b,c,d]`?

Comment: `[]` is an array, `{}` would rather denoting an object.

Comment: search in SO using "javascript array sort" **3,067** results. Didn't those results pop up when you where typing your question?

Comment: Kooilnc: Maybe he's asking about an O(n) sorting algorithm and not a built in function to do it? At least, that's the feeling I'm getting from read the question

Comment: @Soufiane Hassou: turns out his question meant something quite different, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `.sort()` method like:

```
var T = new Array('a', 'd', 'c', 'b');
T.sort();
```

I don't really understand what do you mean by "reordering" (maybe sorting in some random order :)

however you can always use `for` for example:

```
// create new array
var U = new Array();
for (i=0; i<T.length; i++) {

    // some desired condition
    if (T[i] <= 1) {
        // put the value ( T[i] ) on the desired position
        desired_position = ???
        U[desired_position] = T[i];
    }
    else {
        // otherwise put it at the end of the array
        U.push(T[i]);
    }
}

// and here you have the "reordered" array 
alert('the array U is reordered !!');
```

Comment: thanks.. but i am not asking sorting.. i just want to reorder elements for eg: {e,t,m,a} to {t,e,a,m}

Comment: @suba: than I suggest you to change your question into: *How do I sort an array to a certain predefined order [in Javascript]?* (and combine it with te later asked same SO question)

Comment: @suba what should be the criteria for ordering ? How the function should order the array if it looks like this `['h','e','l','l','o'];`

Comment: @suba: If you're not asking about sorting, what does your question mean?  Incidentally, the sort() function accepts as a parameter a reference to a function that handles the comparison between two array elements, so you can implement whatever order you can algorithmically conceive: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml